# Ошибка ImportError: cannot import name "..." from "..."

Tags: python, ооп, python-import

есть 3 файла: main.py / cf.py / fn.py
но при запуске main.py вылезает ошибка:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'hey' from 'fn'
```

main.py:

```
from fn import hey
from cf import cmds

def cherk(vc):
    if vc in question.cmds('hey'):
        sic(x)
```

cf.py

```
from fn import *

class question:
    cmds = {
      ('hey','hello'): hey
}
```

fn.py

```
class answer:
    def hey(self, vc):
        self.hey_rand = ['hello' , 'hello my friend']
        x = random.choice(hey_rand)
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(vc, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `fn` нет `hey`, в `fn` есть класс `answer`, в котором есть функция `hey`. Точно так же в `cf` нет `cmds`.

После того как будут исправлены эти ошибки, вылезет еще пара других.

Comment: сделал но вот 
NameError: name 'hey' is not defined

Comment: Что сделал-то??

Comment: from fn import answer
from cf import question

Comment: эти две строчки не могу выдать указанную вами ошибку. К тому же я сразу написал, что у вас будут еще ошибки. И вообще я порекомендую вам взять учебник. К программированию надо подходить разумно, а не писать код наугад, авось что-нибудь получится.

Comment: ладно, спасибо.

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста
я вроде бы всё сделал сейчас правильно но ошибка теперь
`TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: потому что к элементу словаря нужно обращаться с квадратными скобками [], а не круглыми (). Но просто исправить скобки вам тоже вряд ли поможет, потому у вас в словаре нет элемента "hey"

Answer (score 1):

Цикличная зависимость  циклов, лучше использовать:

```
import SomeModule

def someFunction(arg):
    from some.dependency import DependentClass
```